# CodeIgniter how to connect multi database

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have multi database connection

default connection is in the database.php

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ci_database';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and i have another connection but i want to config this another connection in **models**
or can i pass the connections parameters to the database.php ??

Comment: there is connection in the CI manual

Comment: but what i am looking for is one default connection and another one in Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only CodeIgniter covered this is their online user manual. Oh, wait. They do!

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/database/connecting.html

There's a section entitled "Connecting to Multiple Databases" towards the  bottom of the page.

Comment: You still need to learn to use the CodeIgniter user guide. Found, in seconds, in the 'Models' section: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#conn

Comment: this code for connect

$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "myusername";
$config['password'] = "mypassword";
$config['database'] = "mydatabase";
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;

$this->load->model('Model_name', '', $config);

but how i can switch between database

Comment: By creating a new connection in a different variable, such as `$config2`, and then specifying that for the connection parameter in your controller, i.e. `$this->load->model('Model_name', '', $config2);`.